# Ajax header authentication with key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax request to a URL and receive xml content.

The problem is: There is a validation key that has to be sent before getting access to the content.

The errormessage says:

OPTIONS https://example.com/xxx?agency&=xxx&arrival=xxx&departure=xxx&company=xxx&salesmarket=xxx&adults=xxx

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/xxx?agency&=xxx&arrival=xxx&departure=xxx&company=xxx&salesmarket=xxx&adults=xxx
Response for preflight has invalid http status code 401

```
$.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://example.com/xxx",
      contentType: 'text/xml',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "key xxxxxxx"
      },
        data: {agency: 'xxx', arrival: 'xxx', departure:'xxx',company:'xxx',salesmarket:'xxx',adults:'xxx'},
      success: function (response){
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
```

I have som code written in ASP that works but I would prefer to get the information with the ajax request.

```
      set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
      xmlhttp.Open "GET","https://example.com/xxx?agency&=xxx&arrival=xxx&departure=xxx&company=xxx&salesmarket=xxx&adults=xxx"
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "key", "xxxxxxx"

    xmlhttp.send DataToSend
    response = xmlhttp.responsexml.xml
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Your ASP is setting the header `key` to `xxxxx` while your jQuery call is setting `Authorization` to `key xxxxx`.  Try fixing that.

Comment: Not sure with what you've provided.  Perhaps you're not getting `success` called or there is some other issue.  More info is needed.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong - I didn't help. I'm still getting the samme error.





$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx",
  contentType: 'text/xml',
  headers: {'key': "xxxxxxxx"},
  data: {agency: 'xxx', arrival: 'xxx', departure:'xx',company:'xxx',salesmarket:'xxx',adults:'xxx'},
  success: function (response){
    console.log(response);
  }
});

Comment: Not sure, then, but check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) b/c you're using some outdated jQuery features.

Comment: I'm sorry that I cannot give you more information since I dont have more...

Answer (score 0):

I used php to get the information i needed.

```
    $url = "https://example.com?agency=xxx&arrival=xxx&departure=xxx&company=xxx&salesmarket=xxx&adults=xxx";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "key: xxxxxxx"
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$data = simplexml_load_string($data);

print_r($data);
```